# Determine stateless component name from within that component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I get name of stateless component name inside the same component

For Example : *HelloComponent.jsx*

```
const VHelloComponent = function(props) {
    currentComponentName = ?
    return (<div>Hello React</div>);
}
export default(VHelloComponent);
```

Here, how can I get name of component ? i.e VHelloComponent

Comment: Why do you need the component's name?

Comment: @ Hemerson Carlin  Need to show component name's in debug log.

Comment: In that case VHelloComponent.name should suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

ES6 has implemented the Function.name property. In your case, you could do something like.

`VHelloComponent.name`

```
const VHelloComponent = function(props) {
    currentComponentName = VHelloComponent.name
    return (<div>Hello React</div>);
}
export default(VHelloComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `VHelloComponent.name`, but keep in mind that if you minify your code `.name` will return the minified name of the function. If you minify your code and you need the actual human readable name of the function you can assign a property to your function that contains the name like this do:

```
const VHelloComponent = function(props) {
    currentComponentName = VHelloComponent.myName
    return (<div>Hello React</div>);
}

VHelloComponent.myName = "VHelloComponent";
export default VHelloComponent;
```

Strings won't be minified.